# Facebook Android SDK for Unity: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Working on a Unity game for Android using Facebook's Unity plugin (v5.0.3). Facebook login has been working fine for the majority of our users for a while now. Although recently we received the following crash report from Crittercism. Curious if anyone else has experienced this and has some tips?

Verified that the app is only requesting permissions for the user's email address.

Thanks!

```
Stack Trace
_________________________________
0   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zynga.livepoker/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
1       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
2       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
3       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
4       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
5       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
6       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
7       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
8       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
9       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
13  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
14      at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:1006)
15      at com.facebook.Session.requestNewReadPermissions(Session.java:492)
16      at com.facebook.unity.FB.initAndLogin(FB.java:202)
17      at com.facebook.unity.FB.LoginUsingActivity(FB.java:249)
18      at com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity.onCreate(FBUnityLoginActivity.java:13)
19      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
20      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
21      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
22      ... 11 more
23  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
24      at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:1006)
25      at com.facebook.Session.requestNewReadPermissions(Session.java:492)
26      at com.facebook.unity.FB.initAndLogin(FB.java:202)
27      at com.facebook.unity.FB.LoginUsingActivity(FB.java:249)
28      at com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity.onCreate(FBUnityLoginActivity.java:13)
29      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
30      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
31      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
32      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
33      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
34      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
35      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
36      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
37      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
38      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
39      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
40      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
41      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
42      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it??